# How to pass parameter into a function in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I am trying to build promises for my app. I have something like

```
var test = function(id,companyID) {
    return getProduct(id)
        .then(getProductName(companyID))
        .then(function(obj) {
              console.log(obj)
        })
}

test('123', '456');
```

All I can see is an object that contain empty contexts. However, if I change my code to no include the parameters and hardcode in the `getProductName` function like

```
var test = function(id,companyID) {
    return getProduct(id)
        .then(getProductName)
        .then(function(obj) {
              console.log(obj)
        })
}

test('123', '456');
```

I got the data I need in the console.log

I am not sure how to pass an parameters into the chain. Any idea how to do it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I do not see the function `getProductName` defined anywhere in your sample code.

Comment: @Dalorzo It just a function that return a promise

Comment: Do you want to pass the `companyID` or the result value of the `getProduct(id)` promise to your `getProductName` function?

Comment: getProduct(id) returns nothing, just a function that needs to be run first

Comment: A function that returns nothing is a kind of code smell…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return a promise from a handler, then the promise that was returned from the matching `.then()` adapts to that promise, allowing you to do this:

```
var test = function(id,companyID) {
    return getProduct(id)
        .then(function(){
            return getProductName(companyID)
        })
        .then(function(productName) {
            console.log(productName);
        });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
var test = function(id,companyID) {
    return getProduct(id)
        .then(function(){
            getProductName(companyID)
            .then(function(obj) {
                console.log(obj);
            });
        })
}
```

Comment: it works but can it be more prettier? I feel like it has a lot of nested function here + 1

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this:

```
    var test = function(id, companyID){
    return getProduct(id)
        .then(function(data){
            getproductName(companyID)
                .then(function(data){
                    console.log(obj);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: it works but can it be more prettier? I feel like it has a lot of nested function here + 1

Comment: It is, but you are nesting promises.  Without refactoring the getProduct and getproductName methods, or understanding your app/data structure better, I'd say this is as pretty as it gets :)

Answer (score 1):

When you don't use `getProductName(companyID)` it fails because companyID is undefined so you need to use in your failHandler:

```
var test = function(id,companyID) {
    return getProduct(id)
        .then(getProductName)
        .then(function(obj) {//doneHandler
              console.log(obj)
        },function(obj){//failHandler
              console.log(obj);//now this gets logged
        })
}

test('123', '456');
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem it works IF I don't pass the companyID + 1